# Automatic SBT WAR deploy

Tags: scala, deployment, war, sbt

I'd like to automate deployment process of SBT Web project.

Do you know:

- any working SBT plugin,
- how to create one,
- or how to do this with IntelliJ Idea?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: This can all be found on the SBT wiki. Have you done _any_ reading on it, or do you just expect someone to give a copy&pastable answer?

Comment: I have read the whole Internet but didn't found anything that works.

Comment: the question is a bit too vague.

Anyway, you might wanna have a look at http://blog.vasilrem.com/deploying-to-remote-glassfish-from-sbt-32374